# Verificar itens checados e aplicar a lógica

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Bom dia, estou estudando javascript e me deparei com um problema: Criei uma lógica onde disponibilizo dois botões, um para liberar acesso que quando clicado fica na tela apenas o ícone de check, e o bloquear que quando clicado fica apenas o ícone de bloqueado. O problema é que se podem ser mudado os ícones dos itens checados, porém, mesmo com os dois itens checados o único que muda o ícone é o primeiro. Estou mudando o ícone deixando seu display "none" e "initial" fiz dessa forma porque não conheço outra forma, se souberem algo com javascript agradeço, mas, a questão é como faço para a mudança de ícone acontecerem em todos itens checados e não apenas no primeiro ? Obrigado.

JS:

```
    function bloquearAcesso(){
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".checar");

    for(let i = 0; i< inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].checked == true){

          document.getElementById("liberado").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("bloqueado").style.display = "initial";
      }
  };

    };

  function liberarAcesso(){
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".checar");

        for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
      if (inputs[i].checked == true){
      document.getElementById("bloqueado").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("liberado").style.display = "initial";
      };
  };
  }
```

HTML:

```
<html>    
<body>
<div class="box-body no-padding">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Patio</th>
              <th>Acessar Desktop</th>
              <th>Criado em</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td><input class="checar" type="checkbox">Patio1</td>
              <td> <i id="liberado" class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp; <i id="bloqueado" class="far fa-times-circle"></i></td>
              <td>02/04/2018</td>
              <td>

              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                    <td><input class="checar" type="checkbox">Patio2</td>
                    <td> <i id="liberado" class="fa fa-check"></i> &nbsp; <i id="bloqueado" class="far fa-times-circle"></i></td>
                    <td>02/04/2018</td>
                  </tr>


                  <br/>


          </tbody>


        </table>
        <button onclick="liberarAcesso()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-flat">Liberar acesso</button>
        <button onclick="bloquearAcesso()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-flat">Bloquear acesso</button>


      </div>

      <script src="./curso.js">
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não pode repetir id's. Coloque a id "liberado" como uma class. O mesmo com o id "bloqueado".

Comment: No caso eu usaria o getElementByClassName ? tentei aqui e deu: Não é possível definir a propriedade de Display de undefined. como tem duas classes no ícone, tentei por nome e deu o mesmo erro

Comment: Pode usar `document.getElementByClassName("liberado")` ou `document.querySelectorAll(".liberado")`... aí vc tem que fazer um laço para pegar o elemento pelo índice. O conjunto dos elementos de mesma classe é uma array. Para pegar o primeiro, por exemplo, vc faria: `document.getElementByClassName("liberado")[0]`

Comment: Sam, consegui cara, porém agora quando nenhum está checado ele não acontece nada, tudo certo, porém quando apenas um está checado ele muda o ícone de todos

Comment: Consegui brother, coloquei para checar se o input estava checado a cada loop do for e deu certo, Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dito nos comentários, repetir id's é errado e vai sempre pegar o primeiro elemento com a id. Transforme os id's em class e use `document.querySelectorAll` pegando os elementos pelo respectivo índice:

```js
function bloquearAcesso(){
   let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".checar");

   for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
      if(inputs[i].checked){
          document.querySelectorAll(".liberado")[i].style.display = "none";
          document.querySelectorAll(".bloqueado")[i].style.display = "initial";
      }
   }

}

function liberarAcesso(){
   let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".checar");

   for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
      if (inputs[i].checked){
         document.querySelectorAll(".bloqueado")[i].style.display = "none";
         document.querySelectorAll(".liberado")[i].style.display = "initial";
      }
   }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="box-body no-padding">
   <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Patio</th>
            <th>Acessar Desktop</th>
            <th>Criado em</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td><input class="checar" type="checkbox">Patio1</td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-check liberado"></i> &nbsp; <i class="far fa-times-circle bloqueado"></i></td>
            <td>02/04/2018</td>
            <td>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input class="checar" type="checkbox">Patio2</td>
            <td><i class="fa fa-check liberado"></i> &nbsp; <i class="far fa-times-circle bloqueado"></i></td>
            <td>02/04/2018</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <button onclick="liberarAcesso()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-flat">Liberar acesso</button>
   <button onclick="bloquearAcesso()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-flat">Bloquear acesso</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu mesmo brother, resolvido já. Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, porém gerou outro problema, quando nenhum está selecionado ele funciona corretamente, porém quando eu seleciono apenas um ele aplica a lógica para todos.

```
function bloquearAcesso(){
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#form1 [name=checar]");
    let liberado = document.querySelectorAll("#form1 [name=liberado]");
    let bloqueado =  document.querySelectorAll("#form1 [name=bloqueado]");

    for(let i = 0; i< inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].checked == true){



           for (var x = 0; x < liberado.length; x++){
    liberado[x].style.display = 'none';
    };
                for (var x = 0; x < bloqueado.length; x++){
                    bloqueado[x].style.display = 'initial';
                        };

    };
      }
  };

  function liberarAcesso(){
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#form1 [name=checar]");
    let liberado = document.querySelectorAll("#form1 [name=liberado]");
    let bloqueado =  document.querySelectorAll("#form1 [name=bloqueado]");
    for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        if (inputs[i].checked == true){   

            for (var x=0; x <bloqueado.length; x++){
                bloqueado[x].style.display = 'none';
            };


                for (var x = 0; x < liberado.length; x++){
                    liberado[x].style.display = "initial";
                };
            };



  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido! primeiro coloquei um for para varrer os inputs checados, dentro desse for tem mais dois fors, um para colocar o display none e outro no estado inicial, dentro de cada for exista mais uma verificação para garantir que a lógica será aplicada apenas aos inputs checados. Segue o código caso alguém tenha essa problema.

```
function bloquearAcesso(){
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#form1 [name=checar]");
    let liberado = document.querySelectorAll("#form1 [name=liberado]");
    let bloqueado =  document.querySelectorAll("#form1 [name=bloqueado]");
    for(let i = 0; i< inputs.length; i++){
        if(inputs[i].checked == true){



           for (var x = 0; x < liberado.length; x++){
            let teste = " ";
            if(inputs[x].checked == true){

                teste = liberado[x].style.display = 'none';
    };
};
                for (var x = 0; x < bloqueado.length; x++){
                    if(inputs[x].checked == true){

                    let test = " ";

                    test = bloqueado[x].style.display = 'initial';
                        };

    };
};


      }

  };

  function liberarAcesso(){
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#form1 [name=checar]");
    let liberado = document.querySelectorAll("#form1 [name=liberado]");
    let bloqueado =  document.querySelectorAll("#form1 [name=bloqueado]");
    for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        if (inputs[i].checked == true){   

            for (var x=0; x <bloqueado.length; x++){
                if(inputs[x].checked == true){


                bloqueado[x].style.display = 'none';
            };

        };    
                for (var x = 0; x < liberado.length; x++){
                    if(inputs[x].checked == true){

                    liberado[x].style.display = "initial";
                };
            };



  };
}
}
```